Should I bind the class or just individual elements to an Angular partial component
I have a page (edit.component) made up of several cards. The model for the page is eventItem which has many elements. I have now altered the design so that each card is a partial component - actually two partials one edit and the other readonly. e.g. my edit component for my time card partial will have two datetimepickers for start and end and a numerictextbox for duration. The readonly version of the partial component will have disabled textboxes for all three element. The partials are inserted into the main edit.component.html thus:
<div *ngIf="mode === 'edit'">
    <app-time-card-edit [(eventItem)]="eventItem"></app-time-card-edit>
</div>
<div *ngIf="mode === 'readonly'">
    <app-time-card-read-only [(eventItem)]="eventItem"></app-time-card-read-only>
</div>

Where eventItem - the whole class is passed to the child partial. Is this the best way to do this or should I just pass in the elements that this child partial uses? e.g.
<div *ngIf="mode === 'edit'">
    <app-time-card-edit [(start)]="eventItem.start" [(end)]="eventItem.end" [(duration)]="eventItem.duration></app-time-card-edit>
</div>
<div *ngIf="mode === 'readonly'">
    <app-time-card-read-only [(start)]="eventItem.start" [(end)]="eventItem.end" [(duration)]="eventItem.duration></app-time-card-read-only>
</div>

Thanks.

Having one attribute for each element allows you to only use those attributes that you actually need. If the only place where you use these two components is inside the edit page component, you don't need this degree of flexibility. Particularly if you are still in the development phase where you might still change the elements, you will have less work. I therefore suggest using the first approach unless you really need the flexibility of using only part of the elements. But the difference is small, so I'd say there is no objectively right or wrong way.
